# How to make automatically @timestamp value into elasticsearch7's doc?

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, mapping

I have some problem with setting elasticsearch 7 version.
My purpose is make automatically @timestamp field value after make new doc in ES.

I found some answer about similar question. but it can't be solution because it is different version.

I tried `_default_` object in `mappings` object. But it seems to not provide anymore in ES 7 version.

```
"_default_":{
 "_timestamp" : {
   "enabled" : true,
   "store" : true
 }
}
```

And I want to make @timestamp value in this case.

```
PUT /locations
{
   "mappings": {
         "properties": {
            "location": {
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "text"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

```
PUT /locations/_doc/1
{
  "location" : "31.387593,121.123446",
  "id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

expectd result :

```
{
 @timestamp : "2019-10-23 10:23:50",
 "location" : "31.387593,121.123446",
 "id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an ingest pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/timestamp
{
  "description": "Adds timestamp to documents",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.timestamp",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And call it while inserting documents

```
POST index39/_doc?pipeline=timestamp
{
  "id":1
}
```

Response:

```
{
        "_index" : "index39",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "KWF6920BpmJq35glEsr3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "timestamp" : "2019-10-23T07:17:15.639200400Z"
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Glad could be of help